# Solr Keyword Search

Tags: solr

I have a solr index which contains approx 10 million web discussion threads. The Solr operates in Reader-Writer mode. I have another process which queries solr for different keyword queries. Keywords can be of following formats:

1. A
2. A AND B AND C.....
3. A AND B AND C.... AND Z NOT AA NOT AB NOT AC......

The final Solr Query somewhat looks like this

```
text:( "Keyword A" OR "Keyword B" OR "Keyword C" ...) AND source: (source1 OR source2 OR source3...) AND date:[date1 TO date2]
```

There are around 100 such different combination which are queried on solr. The selection of query combination depends on the number of results each query it returned.

The query somehow seems to take a lot of time. Sometimes it is in minutes (2 - 15 min). The use of cache seems to be difficult as very rarely a query is picked up back to back by scheduling thread.

How can I reduce the time taken for Solr Queries?

Comment: instead of performing a search try to use filter queries whereever possible. Filter cache would be utilized and the performance for the subsequent queries would be faster. ALso what do you mean by Reader-writer mode ?

Comment: The entire flow maintains collection of different queries which are selected one at a time and fired on Solr. Since each query fired is different, will filter cache help? By Reader - Writer, I mean Replication Mode so that I query on one instance and writing is performed on another Solr instance